# "iTunes Store operation failed" when publish app to iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

When I push the app to iTunes connect for beta testing, I am getting the below error. Does my app store submission fail because of this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apple is currently having trouble with some of their services. You can check the status here: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the warning sign and the text "this is just an informational message". It shouldn't be the cause of a rejection.